# Trouble animating a 3D plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate a curve in 3D and am having some trouble.  I've successfully animated some things in 2D, so I thought I knew what I was doing.  In the code below, I generate x, y, and z values parametrically to be a helix and have verified that I can plot the full curve in 3D.  To animate the curve I am trying to begin by plotting only the first two data points and then use FuncAnimation to update the data so that it plots larger portions of the data.  But as I said, it is not working for some reason and I have no idea why; all I get is the initial plot with the first two data points.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.animation as animation

t_max = 10
steps = 100
t = np.linspace(0, t_max, steps)
x = np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(t)
z = 0.1*t

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
line, = ax.plot(x[0:1], y[0:1], z[0:1])

def update(i):
    line.set_xdata(x[0:i])
    line.set_ydata(y[0:i])
    line.set_zdata(z[0:i])
    fig.canvas.draw()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=t, interval=25, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: what does not working mean? is it generating an error? or a blank plot?

Comment: There are no errors, I just get a 3D plot that contains only the first two data points (which looks invisible).  If I include more data in the initial plot command I can see that it is plotting the initial data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally got it to work.  I had a dumb error (frames=t), but also figured out that you need to set the data in the update function differently.  Here is the working code in case anyone is interested.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.animation as animation

t_max = 10
steps = 100
t = np.linspace(0, t_max, steps)
x = np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(t)
z = 0.1*t

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
line, = ax.plot([], [], [], lw=1)
ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.set_zlim(0,1)
plt.show()

def update(i):
    line.set_data(x[0:i], y[0:i])
    line.set_3d_properties(z[0:i])
    return

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=100, interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```